# How to set fields() in Yii2 Restful API

Tags: rest, api, yii2

I would like to list only certain fields in "index" request and list more fields in detail request. For example,

When user calls: http://api.example.com/users, Server returns:

```html
{
  'id':1,
  'name': "John"
},
{
'id':2,
'name': "Henry"
}
...
```

When user calls: http://api.example.com/users/1, server returns:

```html
{
  'id':1,
  'name': "John",
  'gender': "M"
  'dob': "1995-01-01"
  'address': "1 Bay Road"
},
```

How can I set the fields() or extraFields() function to do that without asking user to add new parameters like "expand=gender,dob,address"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the Guide,you could use like this:

```
http://api.example.com/users?fields=id,name

http://api.example.com/users/1?fields=id,name,gender,dob,address
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. That will work. What I would like to do automatically return the different set of data, without asking users to indicate which fields to be returned. Is there a way?

Comment: overwrite fields() method in child class, use child class in detail action
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#fields

Comment: @AaronChen return $model->toArray($fieldArray) instead of return $model in the action of UserController